# Ionic in docker: Error: Please install Android target: "android-23"

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I build docker image from here https://github.com/gleclaire/docker-ionic-framework
and run container with my app. All working good, but when I make

```
ionic build android
```

I see Error:

```
Error: Please install Android target: "android-23".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /opt/android-sdk-`enter code here`linux/tools/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

I can't open the SDK manager by running: /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android because it in docker, and window can not be created.

How I can add target from command line?

Thanks!

Comment: can you run the SDK manager with `--no-ui`? (Make sure you have a TERM env variable set if it complains about no tty.)

Comment: find the android.bat file in the sdk folder, open it as admin, that would open the sdk tools, update the require tools.